# What is taglib uri search sequence?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, uri, taglib

In which places and in which order the Tomcat is searching for taglib tag uri correspondence?

When tld file and it's description in web.xml is required and when is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From chapters 7.3.6.2 and 7.3.6.3 of the [JSP 2.1 specification](http://jsp.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf):

> #### JSP.7.3.6.2 Computing the TLD Resource Path
>
> The following describes how to resolve a taglib directive to compute the TLD 
>    resource path. It is based on the value of the uri attribute of the taglib directive.
>
> - If uri is abs_uri, an absolute URI
>
>   Look in the taglib map for an entry whose taglib_uri is abs_uri. If found, the 
>     corresponding taglib_location is the TLD resource path. If not found, a translation 
>     error is raised.
> - If uri is root_rel_uri, a relative URI that starts with /
>
>   Look in the taglib map for an entry whose taglib_uri is root_rel_uri. If found, 
>     the corresponding taglib_location is the TLD resource path. If no such entry is 
>     found, root_rel_uri is the TLD resource path.
>
> ...
>
> #### JSP.7.3.6.3 Usage Considerations
>
> ...
>
> The use of relative URI specifications in the taglib map enables very short 
>    names in the taglib directive. For example, if the map is:
>
> ```
> <taglib> 
>   <taglib-uri>/myPRlibrary</taglib-uri> 
>   <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/PRlibrary_1_4.tld</taglib-location> 
> </taglib>
> ```
>
> then it can be used as:
>
> ```
> <%@ taglib uri=”/myPRlibrary” prefix=”x” %>
> ```
>
> Finally, the fallback rule allows a taglib directive to refer directly to the TLD. 
>    This arrangement is very convenient for quick development at the expense of less 
>    flexibility and accountability. For example, in the case above, it enables:
>
> ```
> <%@ taglib uri=”/WEB-INF/tlds/PRlibrary_1_4.tld” prefix=”x” %>
> ```